# .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0 Website Upgrade -CSPROJ Error

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, upgrade, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

Good morning Gurus,

I've been searching for this for over a week. I've tried a few solutions but none of them seems to be working for me. I have this old web site created (not by me, by someone else) using VS2003 with .NET 1.1 and now I need to upgrade to .NET 2.0 (no newer versions allowed). I created a new virtual directory in my local IIS environment, changes de App Pool to 2.0, put the solution there and opened it with VS2005. This solution contains 5 (the main project and 4 more in charge of DB connections and other tasks... kind of a N tiers project) projects inside. After VS2005 performs the conversion there are 2 of those projects that are returning the following error:

> The project file must be opened in the Visual Studio IDE and converted
>   to the latest version before it can be built by MSBuild

I have tried:

1. Running MSbuild [projname] from the command prompt
2. Comparing CSPROJ files to see any differences
3. Unloading and loading the project again
4. Using VS2010 to do the conversion (gave me about 200+ errors)

I just cannot figure out what is the difference. I compared the CSPROJ with the other 2 project that seems to pass the conversion and they seem the same.

If it is relevant the application was done using C# (CSPROJ - CS stands for CSharp...)

Please share a little light for me with this. I was just want to be pointed to the right track to fix this because honestly I do not know what else to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem and I want to share my solution with you Gurus. After taking a few steps (including developing a console application that converted the CSPROJ file using MSbuild) I realized that the CSPOJ files were in the correct format. But when I clicked on the error in Visual Studio 2005 it showed me the file in the old format. I have a copy of the application prior to be converted in another directory and the references in my new upgraded version were pointing to those projects. I removed the references to that projects and add them again but know I make sure that the references were pointing to the new CSPROJ files. Problem solved! At least until this point.

I hope this help someone in the future.

Good luck!